# How to convert a string to a binary, then hex, value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

In one column I have a bitstring encoded as a string type. In a different column I wish to have the same bits (potentially starting with a leading 0), but as  a binary value type. Ultimately, I want to have it in hex representation (string or hex type, doesn't matter) in a third column.

How is this done? Do I have to program something for it or is there a faster way?

Input cell contains the following string: 00000100100011000100100011

I wish to obtain the string: 0123123

Comment: Did you try using the [built-in functions](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/engineering-functions-HP005199996.aspx)?

Comment: I don't see anything that converts FROM a string

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a 'bitstring'.  Can you please give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: "0101" of string type should be converted to 0b0101 then 0x3

Comment: `="0x" & BIN2HEX("0101")` should output `0x5`.

Comment: That works when I put in a hardcoded string but when I try to reference the column in bin2hex(), it gives me a number error. Maybe that column isnt a string but another type. Do you know how I can figure out what type/format a column is in?

Comment: I just converted it to a string in another column and I get the same issue, bin2hex gives a number error when referencing a cell containing a string, but not when a string literal is used (as in your example)

Comment: that seems to put it in floating point representation and looses precision

Comment: BIN2HEX is limited to 10 binary digits input. How many are you using?

Comment: twenty seven...

Comment: @WuschelbeutelKartoffelhuhn Consider merging your comments into your original questions and provide an example input you're using along with the expected output you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok i added an example

Comment: I can tell from the way that you converted it that you are looking at your bit string in 4 nibbles. You'll have to somehow tell Excel to split that into 4 nibbles. Otherwise it'll just take

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the binary number with mid(cell, index_start, len) and do a piecewise change of base with bin2hex() followed by a concatenation (via CONCATENATE() - cell references are delimited by ampersands).

Example row:

0010000100000001110100101 is in one cell X1

Split it up into ceil(len(X1)/8)=4 cells to get groups of 8 bits each.

To split it into the 4 cells, use =MID($X1,start_pos,8), where startpos is the starting index (1 based) of the bitstring in X1

In another set of 4 cells concert the previous 4 cells into hex by referencing them with =BIN2HEX(8bitNrCell,2)

Concatenate the previous 4 cells with =CONCATENATE(1stcell&2ndcell&thirdcell&fourthcell)

Comment: since you've done it you may as  well paste the formula that does it, into the answer, it'd be helpful.

Comment: i saw your post just as i was doing it piece-by-piece. thanks anyways. reg the formula, i edited my answer, but i didn't do it in one step so i just list the sequence of functions i used

Comment: I know it was worked out in steps and  not in one go, and it's beneficial to write it as you have(functionally, in steps), but now you worked it out, you have it so you could include the calculation you did. Whether it's one long cell formula (to accompany what you wrote), or a few lines of VBA, to accompany what you wrote. Then in future somebody may post a better one.  And/or it would save a future person some time if they have the same problem.

Comment: And [here a picture that I made](http://i.imgur.com/4BStjTn.png) to explain it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Function CRY_BIN2HEX(arg As String) As String
  Dim rez As String
  Dim lcnt As Integer
  For lcnt = 1 To WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Len(arg) / 4, 0)
    If lcnt = 1 Then
        rez = WorksheetFunction.Bin2Hex(Mid(arg, 1, 4))
    Else
        rez = rez & WorksheetFunction.Bin2Hex(Mid(arg, (lcnt * 4) - 3, 4))
    End If
  Next lcnt
  CRY_BIN2HEX = rez
End Function
```